# Vertically and horizontally center something

Tags: html, css, centering

Vertically and horizontally centering could be one of the most annoying thing for layouting a page.
Even though lots of solutions have been found [See This](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering) and [This](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css), I don't see any of those fits my problem.
My problem is demonstrated here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mESFG).

I tried this for vertical one and it didn't work. Any other for vertical?

```
out {
    display: table;
}

in {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align :middle;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your fiddle. Nothing corresponds to "out" or "in".

Comment: don't worry about the code in the page, Fiddle describes the question@FlavorScape

Comment: it doesn't make any sense. the button is outside the table.

Comment: @FlavorScape Sorry maybe I didn't describe it clearly. They are two things, you are not going to relate them together. The table needs to be vertically align and the button needs to be horizontally align

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to center something vertically and horizontally, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/christianheinrichs/z59wtgxj/9/) is a jsFiddle.

```
#cdiv {
    background-color: #ffff00;
    color: #000000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
}
```

Solution taken from: [Tutorialzine](https://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/)

Comment: the thing is you dont really know the height of the table, it will always be changed

Comment: Then maybe a javascript, which gets the height of the table and adjusts the according CSS property dynamically is the solution.

Comment: Why would you set display to none?

Comment: @S.. Mind you, I wrote this solution years ago, so I don't remember the exact details at all. I did however tweak the jsFiddle a bit just now and found out that the usage of `display: none;` is to initially hide the div container and a table. It is also worth noting that the jsFiddle example does not work with jQuery version 3, only 2 and downwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have aligned your button horizontally by adding

```
margin-right:33%;
margin-left:33%;
```

Now about your table, i have positioned it relative into the div and gave it a top 50%.

**[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mESFG/3/)**

Edit: another way to position your table in your div is to give it margins (top,right,left) in order to position it better.

Hope this helps

Comment: Even thought the horizontal one seems to be hardcoding, it works. But the vertical one doesn't as the table height will be changed

Answer (score 0):

This will center any div both vertically and horizontally in a given area. It will require some math on your part to get it just right. Here is a CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbzgyO

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<!--Content you want centered goes here-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mydiv {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:30em;
    height:30em;
    margin-top: -9em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left: -9em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    background-color:#222126;
}
```

Hope it helps!